# Access to singleton class property in c#

Tags: c#, singleton

Actually I have the next singleton class in c#:

```
public sealed class GlobalInfo
{
    private static readonly GlobalInfo _instance = new GlobalInfo();

    public int Orden { get; set; }

    private GlobalInfo() { }

    public static GlobalInfo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I try to set the Orden property doing this:

```
GlobalInfo.Instance.Orden = 1;
```

I'm getting a

> "doesn't exist in the current context"

error.

Please, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: no, that code works fine

Comment: I failed to reproduce the error. Is it possible that you are trying to use VS debugging tools to inspect the property after it has gone out of scope?

Comment: Jonesopolis, the exact error is "Instance does not exists in the current context". Thank's to all for your help!

Comment: Couldn't you post the complete error message right away?

Answer (score 1):

Try initialising the _instance member of your singleton on the first **GetInstance()** call

```
public sealed class GlobalInfo
{
    private static readonly GlobalInfo _instance;

    public int Orden { get; set; }

    private GlobalInfo() { }

    public static GlobalInfo Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new GlobalInfo();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```